# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'(MongoDB and Django)

Tags: python, django, mongodb

We use MongoDB and Django in our project, some columns have `some_col` element, and some columns don't have `some_col` element, maybe that's why we will get the error of `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`, is there any solution to solve this errors?

```
def get_col(self, name, **kwargs):
    where = {'name': name}
    if 'where' in kwargs and isinstance(kwargs['where'], dict):
        where.update(kwargs['where'])

    find_data = self.find_one(where)
    return find_data

def get_test_col(self):
    colmuns = Test(self.name)
    cls = colmuns.get_col('some_col')
    if not cls:
        self.some_col = {}
    self.some_col = cls.get('data', {}) # error line
```

Comment: can you show me the settings how you integrate mongodb in the django project

Comment: `if not cls: cls = {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extending vestronge's answer:

```py
self.some_col = cls.get('data', {}) if cls else ""
```

Basically sets your column to an empty string if you can't get your query. Feel free to substitute the empty string for anything else.